# Android Blur with RenderScript

Tags: android, renderscript

I try to make a gaussian blur on an android Bitmap but I get this error:

rsAssert failed: !mTypes.size() and
rsAssert failed: !mElements.size()

Here is my code :

```
public Bitmap blurBitmap(Bitmap src) {
    Bitmap outBitmap = src.copy(src.getConfig(), true);

    final RenderScript rs = RenderScript.create(this);
    final Allocation input = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rs, src);
    final Allocation output = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rs, outBitmap);

    final ScriptIntrinsicBlur script =
            ScriptIntrinsicBlur.create(rs, Element.U8_4(rs));
    script.setRadius(25f);
    script.setInput(input);
    script.forEach(output);
    output.copyTo(outBitmap);

    rs.destroy();

    return outBitmap;
}
```

Note that I used android.support.v8.renderscript to ensure compatibility with android lower versions.

Someone would have an idea to fix it?

Thanks.

Martin

Comment: That error is harmless and doesn't actually impact the running code. Does the blur not work? If it doesn't work, can you share the rest of the logcat (and what device/version you are running on)?

Comment: Thanks for your response. Blur works but even with a radius of 25 is not very pronounced. In your opinion how can I get a larger gaussian blur? Can I use an existing renderScript script? Knew you? Thanks. Martin

Comment: I don't understand how a radius of 25 is not very pronounced. What are you starting with as an input image? The RS blur intrinsic only supports up to a radius of 25 today, but you could write a custom script that does more (although it would not be as optimized as the intrinsic).

Comment: I need to call my function 9 times with a radius of 25 to obtain the desired blur. Do you know a trick to get a more pronounced blur still using ScriptIntrinsicBlur? Thanks. Martin

Comment: the samples of android already have one just for blurring. have you checked it out?

Answer (score 3):

The `Element` arguments of `ScriptIntrinsicBlur` should be the same of Allocation's element, so you should use [Allocation.getElement()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v8/renderscript/Allocation.html#getElement()), rather than direct `Element.U8_4(rs)`.

```java
final ScriptIntrinsicBlur script =
    ScriptIntrinsicBlur.create(rs, input.getElement());
```

And you might also want move those `final` to `class private member`, since some of them might be different every time your bitmap is different.

And FYI, `script.setRadius(25f)` is way too high, that will cause slow calculation. If you need such heavy blur, you might consider to scale down the original bitmap at certain level, and blur it, then scale up to your canvas, which will be much faster than heavy blur for a huge image.

One more thing, if you don't care to keep the original bitmap, the allocation of input and output can be the same one, which might save some memory.

Answer (score 1):

While there isn't a good way to increase blur radius, for very large images you can essentially fake it by scaling down (ex .5 original size), blurring, then scaling up to original size. Be careful not to scale too far down as the resulting bitmap will become pixelated.